# Vuejs: Getting slot content componentInstances not rendered due to `v-if`

Tags: vue.js

I want to make a recursive combination of tabs and tree view. Take a look at the simple example below to see it working:

```js
Vue.component('tabs', {
  template: '#tabs',
  data(){
    return {
      tabs:[],
      expanded:true,
    };
  },
  mounted(){
    for (i = 0; i < this.$slots.default.length; i++) {
      let tab = this.$slots.default[i];
      if (tab.componentOptions && tab.componentOptions.tag == 'tab') {
        this.tabs.push(tab.componentInstance);
      }
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('tab', {
  template: '#tab',
  props: ['label']
});

app = new Vue({
  'el': '#inst',
});
```

```html
<!-- templates -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="tabs">
  <div @click.stop="expanded = !expanded">
    <h1><slot name="h" /></h1>
    <div v-if="expanded" class="children">
      <ul><li v-for="tab in tabs">{{tab.label}}</li></ul>
    <div style="border:1px solid #F00"><slot /></div>
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="tab">
  <strong><slot /></strong>
</script>

<!-- data -->
<tabs id="inst">
  <div slot="h">Woot</div>
  <tab label="label">
    <tabs>
      <div slot="h">Weet</div>
      <tab label="sub">Weetley</tab>
  </tab>
  <tab label="label2">Woot3</tab>
</tabs>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
```

So now I have tabs with labels separate, I can add some active state to the tabs and be done.

Except that in order to get the tabs so I can loop through them to make the labels in the parent, I'm looping through `this.$slots.default` to find the tabs. The problem is that when I change the expanded default to false the `v-if` triggers and `componentInstance` is never filled.

I don't want to use `v-show` because the entire reason for using vue is to counteract the performance penalty of a huge DOM and display (Which is how this was previously implemented). How do I get my subcomponents into my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need it to start out expanded, and after `mounted` has run, set expanded to its intended initial value:

```
Vue.component('tabs', {
  template: '#tabs',
  data() {
    return {
      tabs: [],
      defaultExpanded: false,
      expanded: true,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    for (const tab of this.$slots.default) {
      if (tab.componentOptions && tab.componentOptions.tag == 'tab') {
        this.tabs.push(tab.componentInstance);
      }
    }
    this.expanded = this.defaultExpanded;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that could work. Does this add overhead for rendering all the dom elements, or does vue keep it all under wraps until it's done?

Comment: I *think* it will do all its work in the virtual dom and not do any real-dom rendering.

Comment: Thanks, I'll tick this and save the next question for tomorrow